# Programming GIS - don't understand why TypeError is occurring

Tags: python, gis

Traceback:

```
  File "C:/Users/tobad/PycharmProjects/myprog/gisp2020-master/CA2_2020_sample.py", line 105, in get_stuff_from_geoserver
    crs_trans = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(int(incoming_points_epsg), int(incoming_polys_epsg), always_xy=True)
TypeError: from_crs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'always_xy'
```

Code:

```
crs_trans = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(int(incoming_points_epsg), int(incoming_polys_epsg), always_xy=True)

if incoming_points_epsg != incoming_polys_epsg:
    for point in filtered_points:
        p = shape(point["geometry"])
        x, y = crs_trans.transform(p.x, p.y)
        p = mapping(p)
        p["coordinates"] = (x, y)
        point["geometry"] = p
```

Comment: What version of pyproj are you using?

Comment: `always_xy` was added in 2.2.0, so make sure you're using at least that version - https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_crs